# Error inserting data into AlwaysEncrypted column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Using the new **AlwaysEncrypted** feature, I encrypted a **DateTime** column in one of my tables and this is the error I'm getting when trying to insert a new date:

```
Message: [SqlException: Operand type clash: datetime2(7) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDb') is incompatible with datetime encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDb') Statement(s) could not be prepared.]
```

I've been getting insertion errors for strings too, but after changing the data type from varchar(24) *(for example)* to **nvarchar(max)** everything worked smoothly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it is an **Entity Framework** issue. So althought I initially used model first, the **.NET DateTime** was converted to a **Sql datetime**, but then EF uses **Sql datetime2** for binding.

The wired thing is that I never got an error before converting the column to **Always Encrypted**. Why this never occurred before is still a mystery to me, but the sql below has solved my issue. I highly recommend running this before applying Always Encrypted to the column, just to avoid further errors:

```
ALTER TABLE [TestTable] ALTER COLUMN Dob datetime2
```

Answer (score 0):

For an **encrypted** (deterministic) column of **SQL 2016**, with **EF6** migration -- even though the model has the attribute to specify its data type as datetime, still EF pushes it as datetime2(7) only and throws the clash error reported on this thread, Even manually altering the migrations file wont solve this issue.

The only **solution** is to use data type **datetime2(7) instead of datetime** in SQL database.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// *this wont work*
    /// </summary>
    [Column("addedDate", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
```